# Laravel: Retrieving A Record By Column Value

Tags: database, laravel, orm

How can I get a record by a value of a column. For example, I want the dataset where the column "foo" has the value "bar".

I didn't marked "foo" as unique key, but I could do so if its necessary.

I tried

```
$order = Order::where('foo', '=', $bar)->get();
```

but I assume that gives back not just one dataset but an array of datasets, right?

The documentation is very poor and I cannot find an adequate answer with google. Thats a simple task for an orm, i dont know why its so complicated.

Comment: yea it can be array of object because that can be return more than one raw. what do you expect in return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. If you want the first returned alone. Using `->get()` will always return an arrayable object

```
$order = Order::where('foo', $bar)->first();
```

If you want to make it reusable then you should do this. In `Order.php` model (assuming its an Eloquent model).

```
public static function scopeFoo($query, $value) {
    return $query->where('foo', $value);
}
```

Now you can do this in your controller or anywhere

```
Order::foo($bar)->first()
```

Comment: hm it tells me: Non-static method App\Order::getByOrderIdent() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context